# Identifying the Test Directories in a Java Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, junit, mockito, pom.xml

I have not followed the general Maven project structure in my Project. This is how my project structure looks like -

> ```
> ProjectName
>  |- src
>     |- app
>        |- models
>        |- services
>     |- test
>        |- unit
>           |- services
>        |- integration
>           |- services
> ```

For the test I am using **Junit** and **Mockito**. My **pom.xml** file looks like this -

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ProjectName</groupId>
  <artifactId>ProjectName</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.10.19</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

The problem that I am facing now is, when I am running my tests it is not able to find the dependency packages junit and mockito. I know it is because I have declared the **scope** of these dependecies as test.

What I want to know is, what change should I make in my pom.xml file so that Maven can indentify my test directory?

Comment: "*I have not followed the general Maven project structure in my Project"*.. why?

Comment: I was an old legacy project, which I converted to a Maven project using this link: http://crunchify.com/how-to-convert-existing-java-project-to-maven-in-eclipse/

Comment: And I don't have the luxury to refactor the project structure right now. In future, I am definitely planning to do that, but currently, I an blocked with the existing task in hand.

Comment: Refactoring the project structure should take you lesser time as compared to retrofitting the structure to maven IMO with the added advantage that your project is maven compliant.

Comment: I can give it a shot, but I have to do the impact analysis once before that. I thought to make changes in the pom.xml file would be much simpler.

Comment: *Simpler* is subjective. What seems simple now can become a big pain in the future. That said, I still don't think it should be that tough to change the project structure. Good luck.

Comment: the <build> section of your pom specify the source directory. Have you tried to specify the **testSourceDirectory** as well?

Comment: I added this line <testSourceDirectory>src/test</testSourceDirectory>, below this line: <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>. But it didn't work. Am I doing it right @alainlompo?

Comment: Change the directory structure and follow the conventions this is the first thing which should always being done during a migration from other tools to Maven....If you change the structure now you can use the conventions which makes the migration and usage much easier ....it will safe many time if you make the change now cause it only costs a few changes in directory structure...and simplifies the configuration in Maven dramatically...

Answer (score 4):

The [Maven surefire plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html) will look for tests in the directory the property `project.build.testSourceDirectory` is pointing to.

So you can add this to your pom.xml to change the value of this property:

```
<build>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test</testSourceDirectory>
</build>
```

This will execute all tests (unit and integration) in the test phase. If you dont want to execute the integration tests, you can set the property to `${project.basedir}/src/test/unit`.

Answer (score 3):

I would also suggest to follow the conventions for maven projects as others did.

Still, things should work by overriding following maven properties as below:

```
<properties>
  <!-- Considering src/app will have all your sourcr java code -->
  <project.build.sourceDirectory>src/app</project.build.sourceDirectory>
  <!-- Considering all your junit tests are in src/test/unit -->
  <project.build.testSourceDirectory>src/test/unit</project.build.testSourceDirectory>
  ...
</properties>
```

If you want to add integration test with maven, then I would suggest to go over [this](https://www.testwithspring.com/lesson/running-integration-tests-with-maven/) article.

You can remove `<sourceDirectory>` and `<resources>` from `<build>` section.